# How to create a form using block module in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want build a form using a block module in `Drupal 8`. I am aware of building the forms in `Drupal` 7 but the same seems to be different in Drupal 8.

Request anyone who has worked on drupal8 custom forms as block to help me.

Answer (score 30):

Your question is very vague, as I don't know how much you already know about modules, forms and blocks in Drupal 8. So here is a small guide what to do, further information on how to do stuff in detail would be overkill for this answer.

**1. Create a new module and enable it**

Look here: [Naming and placing your Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2116781).

Basically you create the module folder and the module info yml file to let Drupal know about the module. Then you enable it using drush or the admin area in Drupal.

**2. Create the form**

Look here: [Introduction to Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411).

under `your_module/src/Form` you create the form. More details in the link above.

**3. Create the block and render the form**

Look here: [Create a custom block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2101565).

under `your_module/src/Plugin/Block/` you create the block which will render the form.

The idea is basically (code updated with suggestion from Henrik):

```
$builtForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\your_module\Form\Your‌​Form');
$renderArray['form'] = $builtForm;

return $renderArray;
```

Note: You don't need to wrap the `$builtForm` with the `$renderArray`, you can return just the `$builtForm` and be fine. I just personally like to do it that way, because often times I need to add something else to the final render array like some markup, cache settings or a library etc.

**4. Place the block**

Place the block in the desired region(s). Done.

Comment: HI Frank, Thanks for your replay .

Comment: HI Frank, Thanks for your reply. I was actually trying to implement a form within a block.I am just posting the URL which represents the same.http://www.vliegtarieven.nl/ ...Kindly go through and suggest me way to build the flight booking form in home page.

Comment: I already did, just look at my answer :) I am not sure what you expect from me. I am certainly not going to dictate every single line of code, because that's not what StackOverflow is about. If you have absolutely no idea about forms and so on, just google for tutorials or something, there are plenty.

Comment: You can directly build the form with: `$builtForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\yourmodule\Form\YourForm');` – anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @FrankDrebin Is there a way to order the items that get returned? I'm returning a form and some markup, but the form always ends up after the markup and I'd like to get the form above the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed summary of how to go about this:-

https://www.sitepoint.com/building-drupal-8-module-blocks-forms/

Following the above guide, you would add the completed form to the block build function, e.g.

```
class DemoBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {    
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\demo\Form\DemoForm');
    return $form;
  }

}
```

Some more useful docs if you are new to Drupal 8 or need to dust off your knowledge:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/block-api

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api

Answer (score 0):

To build a form using block module, you can easily use [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) where you can add a form and display as a block.

---

If you mean to create a form programatically in the custom block, you can achieve that by creating two files shown below:

Form file (`src/Form/DemoForm.php`):

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\demo\Form\DemoForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\demo\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;

class DemoForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'demo_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {

    $form['email'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your .com email address.')
    );
    $form['show'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, array &$form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    if (strpos($values['email'], '.com') === FALSE ) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('email', t('This is not a .com email address.'));
    } 
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, array &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('Your email address is @email', array('@email' => $form_state['values']['email'])));
  }

}
```

<sup>Source: [Building a Drupal 8 Module: Blocks and Forms](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-drupal-8-module-blocks-forms/).</sup>

Block file (`src/Plugin/Block/HelloBlock.php`):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "form_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("My form"),
 *   category = @Translation("My Category"),
 * )
 */
class HelloBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\mymodule\Form\HelloBlock');
    //$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'example') .  '/js/example.js';
    //$form['#markup'] = $this->t('Custom text');
    return $form;
  }

}
```

<sup>Source: [Create a custom block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block).</sup>

---

To add a form to the *Block Configuration*, see: [Add a Form to the Block Configuration](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-form-to-the-block-configuration).