# How to render custom form inside a custom block programmatically with drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I need render a custom form in a custom block programmatically. This is my code inside a controller:

```
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\wa_encuesta\Form\NewForm', $extra);
[enter image description here][1]  $form=render($form);

  $blockContent = BlockContent::create([
    'info' => $title,
    'type' => 'basic',
    'body'=>[
      'value' => $form,
      'format' => 'full_html'
    ]
  ]);
  $blockContent->save();

 //$block = Block::create([
 $block =  \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::create([
   'id' => 'about_us',
   'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $blockContent->uuid(),
   'region' => 'header',
   'provider' => 'block_content',
   'weight' => -100,
   'theme' => \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default'),
   'visibility' => array(),
   'settings' => [
     'label' => 'About us',
     'label_display' => FALSE,
   ],
 ]);
 $block->save();
```

The form render a custom block but this not working when submit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get this done by combination of hook_preprocess_block or hook_preprocess_node and twig file.

Example:
Say, you want to render this in a block:
Define hook_preprocess_block() in your theme file:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $blockId = $variables['elements'][#id];
  //check for your block id
  $render_service = Drupal::service('renderer');
  $form_html = $render_service->renderPlain(Drupal\wa_encuesta\Form\NewForm::class, $extra);
  //set in variables
  $variables['my_form_html'] = $form_html;
}
```

Now, identify your twig file name for your block, and just put:

```
{{ my_form_html }}
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your answer. I am working in a poll custom module. The administrator can create many polls from custom administrative user interfaz and he can position the poll in any region on the page. Please open the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1vCY__6eSJAvksEttNmUefe4QdVLzEy/view

PS:
I have some experience in drupal development modules(Google Maps API, Forms, create tables and others).

Answer (score 0):

please see my answer to the same question here: [How to create a form using block module in drupal 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643474/how-to-create-a-form-using-block-module-in-drupal-8/36646398#36646398)

Basically you just create a separate form and a block, render the form in the block and then place the block in the desired region.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks so much for your answer. I am working in a poll custom module. The user can create many polls from custom administrative user interfaz and he can position the poll in any region on the page. Please open the link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1vCY__6eSJAvksEttNmUefe4QdVLzEy/view

PS:
I have some experience in drupal development modules(Google Maps API, Forms, create tables and others).